# Can gradle script property extensions be shared between different scripts

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

If there is a build.gradle file as follows:

```
...
apply from: 'Other.gradle'

task hello {
    project.ext.hello = "hello"
}
```

And Other.gradle has:

```
task getHello {
    println project.ext.hello
}
```

I get an error saying:

> Cannot get property 'hello' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

Is there a way to share property extensions between the scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting ext.hello then have the tasks update it

== build.gradle

```
ext {
  hello = null
}

apply from: 'Other.gradle'

task hello {
  doLast {
    hello = "hello"
  }
}
```

== Other.gradle

```
task getHello {
  doLast {
    println hello
  }
}
```

If you really want to be able to set info on a task, you can also use the ext on a task and scope it to a task. If you were implementing a larger plugin you could create an extension and set it on the task.